# Tableau Display Not Enough Data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard that has some identifiable information (salaries and places of work for example) and wanted to some how make my dashboards not show the table/graph if the numbers of students in the combination of filters is 10 or less.  I thought about a third sheet floating behind the table/graph (this is on a filter to swap between which view you want) but it only works when there is zero data.  Is there a way to do a calculation to say: IF count(distinct) of data < 10 THEN display "Not Enough Data" ELSE show data?

Comment: There was a presentation at Tableau Conference 2018 where this was addressed. The whole presentation is available at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwPg7S7STZk. The presenter discusses how to suppress data in your use case. They use level-of-detail calculations with IF statements.

Comment: Delayed reply but this video was informative but missed a little of what I want to show.  I tried to follow his guide but his just hides the counts.  What I would want is if the count is below some threshold (10 or less) then the graph/table is just empty and its like its a blank page.  That way I could hide a floating text box behind it that says not enough data text